# [ERROR] Failed to load nodelet

Tags: husky, cmake, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i try to move my Husky A200 a little bit smoother. Therefor i've installed the yocs_velocity_smoother. But it doesn't start. Nodelet failed to load. I saw that others have nearly the same problems and they only must add a new library through the "CMakeLists.txt" file. But i don't know which library i had to add. My error look like this:

```
[ERROR] [1371736335.535348833]: Failed to load nodelet [/velocity_smoother] of type [yocs_velocity_smoother/VelocitySmootherNodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin yocs_velocity_smoother/VelocitySmootherNodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1371736335.535624567]: Service call failed!
```

thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65595/%5Berror%5D--failed-to-load-nodelet/) by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running multiple machines? If so make sure the yocs_velocity_smoother is installed on the remote machine.  (The machine running the nodelet_manager is the critical one)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0